# Phone Number validation using Regular Expression validation in c# 2008?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-3.5

I Want to validate the phone number in this format i.e +919981424199,+91231456789,....
I am using Asp.net +c#2008 for developing web site.for this i have  used the Regular Expression validation control->property->Validation Expression="[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*".
But this accept the number as 919981424199,.....
User may be enter in this way +919981424199,919300951916,so on
so  i need the validation expression for this type format.The "+" symbol is optional it can be use & it can't.I tried  to solve but still i am searching.please help me to sort out this problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `\+?\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Running this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(phoneNumberTextBox.Text, @"(?<=^|,)\+?\d+");
while (match.Success)
{
    string phoneNumber = match.Groups[0].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Found phone number: " + phoneNumber);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

with this data:

```
+919981424199,919300951916
```

Produces this output:

```
Found phone number: +919981424199 
Found phone number: 919300951916
```