# RegEx for valid Mobile Phone Number country code 0092 or +92

Tags: c#, java, php, asp.net, regex

Is there a standardised regular expression for all valid mobile phone numbers, e.g.  00923465655239, or +923005483426,00923335612513 i am searching it quit two days but i havnot found any expression for these format.

country code 0092 or +92 and mobile total numbers after 0092  are 10 numbers

Advance thanks

Comment: How about learning regex by trying to write this one?

Comment: Your first example, 0092346565239, has only 9 digits after 0092. Is it really valid?

Comment: Don't validate phonenumbers, it's just too much trouble for the client and for you.

Comment: Did this work for you? [previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: i have no knowledge in regex.

Comment: @TimS sorry its 00923465655239  these are 10 digits

Comment: Thanks god some of us are born with knowledge in regex :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$number =  "00923005483426" ; //Use another number to test   
$pattern = "/^(\+|00)92\d{10}$/" ;

$isOk = preg_match($pattern, $number) ;
var_dump($isOk) ;
```

Should do the work.

Comment: its givig wrong output when i used it. like for example 00923465735234

Comment: Check it once again. It gives the correct result. `$number =  "00923465735234" ; //Use another number to test   
$pattern = "/^(\+|00)92\d{10}$/" ;

$isOk = preg_match($pattern, $number) ;
var_dump($isOk) ;`

Answer (score 4):

I am not going to provide you an answer, I am going to provide you with a bit of information which you can *read through and learn* yourself how to use regex.

This search took me less than 5seconds to grab the URL for you.

Here is a good regex phone number validation [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

This shows you with a lot of description how to use regex for validating phone numbers. 
I suggest you take a read of this, make an attempt and then if you get stuck then we will be more than happy to help.

If that proves difficult then use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895358/phone-number-validation-using-regular-expression-validation-in-c-sharp-2008)